# How to exit a loop on condition?

Tags: php

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    $i=0;
    if($i==1||$i==2){continue;}
    echo $value;
    $i++;
}
```

I am a newbie of PHP, now i do a test, and i want to go out the loop not output 2 and 3, why the above code doesn't work?

Comment: use `break;` inside if condition

Comment: You need to use `break` to get out, `continue` is to go to the next element in iteration. see php manual for more infos.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's because you set `$i = 0;` on each iteration (Hence your check for `$i==1||$i==2` will never match). Variable initialization go outside the loop:

```
$arr = array(1, 2, 3, 4);
$i   = 0;
foreach ($arr as $value) {
    if ($i == 1 || $i == 2) {
        continue;
    }
    echo $value;
    $i++;
}
```